# Hot Reload does not work in Visual Studio for Mac 8.10.10 (build 8). Tried to create a new project but also does not work

Tags: ios, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to solve this error for 2 days, but it doesn't work(Appeared about 4 days ago).
Maybe someone has already encountered this problem and has a solution.

**XAML Hot reload output**
`[7:31:28 AM] XAML Hot Reload is using 'full page' mode`
`[7:32:02 AM] Xaml Changed for 'MainPage.xaml' in 'HotReloadTest', sending to app...`

**Already tried** to run the project from the folder, reinstall VS for mac but nothing works

**Errors Messages**
`/Users/OlegLysiak/Projects/HotReloadTest/HotReloadTest/MainPage.xaml(1,1): Information: XLS1106: Setting x:DataType will enhance IntelliSense when working with data bindings. (HotReloadTest) IntelliSense`

I will be grateful to you.
Oleg Lysiak.

**Application Output**

````
2021-10-07 07:31:52.841259+0300 HotReloadTest.iOS[1677:54109] SecTaskCopyDebugDescription: HotReloadTest.iO[1677]/0#-1 LF=0
2021-10-07 07:31:52.853446+0300 HotReloadTest.iOS[1677:54109] SecTaskLoadEntitlements failed error=22 cs_flags=200, pid=1677
2021-10-07 07:31:52.853899+0300 HotReloadTest.iOS[1677:54109] SecTaskCopyDebugDescription: HotReloadTest.iO[1677]/0#-1 LF=0```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue as reported [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/XAML-Hot-Reload-does-not-load-with-Xamar/1543082) and being worked on. A fix should be there soon!

Comment: Thanks. Waiting for fix.